# Doubt about prime counting formula using Wilson's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

In a paper by C. P. Willans [(Here)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.jstor.org/stable/3611701&ved=2ahUKEwirnOCB8prlAhUC63MBHfEGD5oQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw3Xj-NgxIprS7q2gbCs-rYW%20) ;
He Introduced a following elementary formula for prime counting function .

$$\pi (n)=\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(\pi \frac{(j-1)!^{2}}{j}\right)}{\sin^{2}(\frac{\pi }{j})}$$

I also read in some paper that these type of formulas don't have a practical use (?) . So I tried to justify it by following observation and/or difficulties:

As we can see the $!$ can be replaced by $\Gamma$ .

(1)So, the $\frac{\sin^{2}\left(\pi \frac{(j-1)!^{2}}{j}\right)}{\sin^{2}(\frac{\pi }{j})}$ (summand ) is analytic for $j>0$ ( we can include zero in the domain by shifting the $j$ in summand by 1).

(2)The summand is in purely distributional sense

(3) Also , It oscillate violently in Right half plane .( So criteria for most of the analytic summation formulas ruled out ).

(More possible difficulties?)

> Question :
>
> Although with the given difficulties , summand is analytic in non negative domain ; So , is there any way to get an asymptotic estimate for prime counting function using this formula ?
>
> Are there any other (stronger) difficulties than mentioned above which are obstructing the formula to be analysed asymptotically ?
>
> At least can we expect to prove infinitude of primes using this ? (If not what's the reason for it's impenetrable nature )?